# Browser History Management

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, back-button, browser-history

I'm trying to find a clean solution to working with the browser history in the most effective way. (I'm using GWT, but this question is really more general than that.)

Here's my situation (I would think it's pretty standard):

I have a web application that has several different pages/places/locations (whatever you want to call it), which I display in response to changes to the browser history. Beyond the usual "Home", "Features", "Contact", etc. which are mostly static HTML pages, there is a "User" section, where people can log into their user accounts and (let's call it) a "Project" section, where users can work on their projects.

So, now I simply use local links called *#Home*, *#Features*, *#Contact*, etc., as well as *#User*, *#Project* to get to the different pages. And everything is fine, except the following scenario:

If someone opens the link *#Project*, for example, that person is shown a project login dialog. This login dialog has a <kbd>cancel</kbd> button, which I would like to implement simply by calling the browser's <kbd>back</kbd> button from my app (easy enough). The reason I would like to do this, is two-fold:

1. You can get to this login dialog from several different locations in the app, as well as your bookmarks, and with this approach I wouldn't need to keep track of where the user came from.
2. Much more importantly: If I instead did remember where the user came from (e.g. *#Home*) and linked the user "forward" to return to that place, I get the following effect:

   - Let's say the user visits *#Home*, then *#Features*, and then clicks on project login.
   - If the user clicks the <kbd>cancel</kbd> button and I send him "forward" to *#Features*, a click on the browser's <kbd>back</kbd> button afterwards would bring back the login dialog, then again *#Features* and finally *#Home*. Not really what you would expect.
   - Instead you'd want to get back to *#Home* immediately, just what you get if I simply implement <kbd>cancel</kbd> via the browser's back function.

At this point everything is great, except when the user initially goes to this login dialog via a direct bookmark link to *#Project*. Because then, if I simply have <kbd>cancel</kbd> = <kbd>back</kbd>, the user is sent away from the page entirely back to his browser's start-page or wherever he was before. So, in this case, I do need to link "forward" to *#Home*.

Now, I've tried to think of several ways to fix this and have come up with a couple of solutions, but none seem very desirable to me, but let me share them anyways to maybe stir up some creativity:

- When the page is first opened, grab the history token. If it's *#Project* or *#User* or anything else that triggers a cancelable dialog, place the following items onto the history stack: *#Home*, *#Project*, where the last one is the saved initial token. This, then, allows my <kbd>cancel</kbd> button to function correctly... once... But, if a user clicks <kbd>back</kbd> afterwards, he will get the login dialog again (since the original history token is still in the history stack and I don't know how to clear it). A click on <kbd>cancel</kbd> then would take him off the page (inconsistent behavior).
- I could instead place *#+++*, *#Home*, *#Project* onto the stack, which would then allow me to catch a <kbd>back</kbd> click that would take the user off the page by detecting the *#+++* link and simply re-adding the *#Home* token onto the stack. This would solve the problem and works beautifully overall, except that I hate websites that don't let you back out of them without hammering the back button quickly enough...
- The cleanest solution would be, if I could somehow keep track of the length of the history stack as far as places in my app are concerned. Easy enough at the start: It's got one item on it. But what if I get a sequence of places like this: *#Home*, *#Features*, *#Home*? Did the user click <kbd>back</kbd> to get back to *#Home*, i.e. the history is now length 1 in the browser, or did he click on the *#Home* link, i.e. the history is length 3? My idea for detecting this would be:

  - Define, that *#Home* is the same as *#home*.
  - Have all links in the page link only to the upper-case version of the link.
  - Whenever you get a history change notification that starts with an
    upper-case letter, immediately add two more items to the history,
    the first beginning with a lower-case letter and the second also beginning with an upper-case letter. I.e. *#Home* is turned into *#Home*, *#home*, *#Home*.
  - If you ever get a history change that starts with a lower-case letter, you know the user just clicked <kbd>back</kbd> rather than a link and you simply click <kbd>back</kbd> two more times for him to actually get back to the previous page.
  - Now you can distinguish between "backward" and "forward" links and maintain an accurate history model in the code.
  - But, unfortunately, there's two problems with this: For one, the browser history get's cluttered with crap (not very elegant) and, second, the system starts to break down, if the user ever clicks <kbd>back</kbd> quickly enough so that your app doesn't have time to react to the message.

It seems like this should be a very common problem and I am hoping that one of you can point me to a more useful direction than my thoughts have so far.

Comment: Have you considered using a client-side routing system like the one provided by angularjs? http://angularjs.org It can use html5's push stake to keep track of back and forward plus will give you the tools to handle a client arriving at the route directly.

Comment: @thatjuan angularjs seems to be extremely feature rich and will probably take a while to sift through. Do you know enough about it to summarize in a couple sentences the parts that are relevant to my question? That would be extremely helpful, thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at Activities and Places? https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces  Any reason you try to invent your own solution?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Unfortunately, I don't think that the Activities and Places framework has a solution to this particular problem either. It doesn't seem to have a way to tell me about whether a "back" call will take me off-page or is safe or to allow me to insert a "home" place into the current spot on the history. Unless, maybe, I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

[`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history) has a `length` attribute that will show you how many entries are in the history for the current tab.  It is unfortunately *not* filterable (so there is no way to say `window.history.localURLs.length`).

If you are doing this almost entirely on the client side (i. e. partial updates, very few full-page loads, using hashes or the `history.(push|pop)State` API) then you may want to look into incorporating a client-side routing framework into your application to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: NICE! This is exactly the simple detail I was hoping for that would help me solve this. Now all I need to do is store history.length when the page first loads and then have my "back" function check if there is something to go back to, and if not, turn it into a "home" link! SWEET! Thank you! I'm surprised GWT doesn't expose this. Is it fully cross-browser? I'll try it right now.

Comment: ARGH! It ALMOST works! Except that the history length that it returns is not just the number of times that I can still click "back", but it also includes the number of times I could click "forward"! With that, it doesn't work any more... Is there an equivalent that only returns the "back" count?

Comment: @Markus - unfortunately, there is not.

Comment: I found a way to do it! I simply link the user "forward" to a dummy-link to clear the forward part of the history and then hit "back" from my program, which makes sure I only have one "forward" link in the list. Now, it's reliable! Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this approach isn't working reliably in all browsers, that's why I had to un-accept this answer in the hope of finding a solution that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Before your user can access #LOGIN dialog, your entry point class is executed. In this class you can remember the last known page. In Login activity/presenter you can add a browser history event handler, which checks if the last known place is null or not. If null, send a user to the #HOME page.

You don't need to ask the browser which places in your app a user has visited. You can remember the entire history of each session, if you want to: i.e. [#HOME, #LOGIN, #FEATURES, #HOME].

Comment: How can I make sure that I remember the history correctly, if the user navigates around randomly using the browser's history buttons? All I can do is maintain my own history, which assumes that every move is a "forward" move. So, if the user clicks "Home", "Features", BACK, then my history would now contain "Home", "Features", "Home", whether the browser's history just contains "Home". Not sure I understand how I can use this to make a decision about how to handle a dialog cancel click?

Comment: In your original question you describe a very specific problem: back to another website. You only need to know if your own history record is null or not to solve that problem. Other than that, let the browser manage the history.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't provide me that information, though. I will never be able to tell whether a user got back to the "null" state or not. Let's say I see the page-transitions "Home", "Features", "Home" (from above). Is the user now in a position where BACK takes me off the page? or back to "Features"? I.e. did he get to the second "Home" by clicking BACK or a link on the "Features" page, or another bookmark somewhere? This is the detail I need to solve.

Comment: If your history ends with [..., #HOME, #FEATURES], and the next token is #HOME, you can safely assume it's a move back. Logically there is no difference between clicking on Home link or pressing a back button in this situation.

Comment: ??? There's a HUGE difference, because if the user clicked on the #HOME link in the #FEATURES section and I issue a "back" command from my code, he will safely end up back on my page in the #FEATURES section, but if the user got back to #HOME by clicking the "back" button in the browser rather than a link, if I issue another "back" command from my code, I will kick him off my page! And that distinction is exactly my problem!

Answer (score 0):

How about you have a `Queue<String> historyQueue;`

When the page loads for the first time, i.e. `onModuleLoad()` you initalize the `Queue`.
When you capture a history event, check if its a back or a new history token.
If its a back, you pop it out from the queue, if its a new one you add it to the queue. This way, the cancel button is just a `token = historyQueue.pop()` and check if the token is null. If it is, then like you said `back = cancel`, so just do the appropriate thing.

Comment: That would be a great solution, except for two problems: Unfortunately, I don't think there is a reliable way to detect whether a page change is a "forward" or a "backward" change. And, even worse, if this was somehow possible, there is probably nothing you can do to correctly handle the ability of many browsers to jump around randomly in the history.