# Inserting "Home" hash into browser history

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history

I would like to achieve the following:

If a user opens a link to some sub-page in my website, like index.html#Contact, I would like to add the index.html# token onto the history stack before the index.html#Contact token, so that the user, when clicking the browser's <kbd>back</kbd>-button first ends up on the start-page of my site and then on the next <kbd>back</kbd> actually leaves the page as normal.

I thought I could achieve this very easily with the following javascript that gets executed "onload":

```
var href = window.location.href;
var hashPos = href.indexOf("#");
if ((hashPos > 0) & (hashPos+1 < href.length)) {
    window.location.replace(href.substring(0, hashPos+1));
    window.location.assign (href);
}
```

But for some reason, this doesn't do anything at all...

I got it to work in Firefox like this:

```
var href = window.location.href;
var hashPos = href.indexOf("#");
if ((hashPos > 0) & (hashPos+1 < href.length)) {
    window.location.replace(href.substring(0, hashPos+1));
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.assign(href);
    }, 0);
}
```

But in IE and Chrome, this doesn't do anything either...

Any suggestions (other than "don't do this!")?

Comment: "Any suggestions" - don't mess with the user's history in this way. It's a bad user experience. If I click on a link and go to a page, I expect to be taken back to where I was when I hit the back button.

Comment: @zzzzBov I'm just simplifying things for the question... I wouldn't do this for all subpages, especially not Contacts. Only if the user links to a subpage that actually pops up a light-box login dialog. In that case, it makes perfect sense that a click on "back" is the same as hitting "cancel" on the login dialog (i.e. taking you back to the start page/closing the dialog) and after that everything works as normal...

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense that "back" would be the same as "cancel". The only way it would make sense is if they had clicked a link or button on the page, which they obviously had not. If they want to close the lightbox, provide them with a close button and be done with it. Don't mess with their history unless the user is performing actions that are changing page context.

Comment: I know you're not using jQuery here, but [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/) is an awesome option that is hyper-compatible.

Comment: @zzzzBov Let's just say it's a page that only I want to use and it's the way I want it to work... I really hate it that every time you ask almost any question about "HOW do I achieve the following?" in an online forum there is at least one guy why comes back with "DON'T do it!". It's not helpful...

Comment: @crowjonah That might still be very useful as I can probably see how they are doing it. Thanks! If I find a solution there, I'll post it here.

Comment: @Markus, It's called the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which is when you ask questions about a perceived solution when the solution is not appropriate for the actual problem.

Comment: @zzzzBov I tried asking about the actual problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576848/browser-history-management Nothing useful came of it... (The accepted answer, turns out, doesn't work reliably, so I'm trying to find a better one. This here is my attempt.)

Comment: @Markus, you asked that question less than a day ago, and already accepted an answer. If you want better answers, you have to have some patience. If you're *desperate* for better answers, you'll need to assign a bounty to the question. If the answer doesn't work reliably ***don't accept it***. It's your own fault there.

Comment: @zzzzBov Until 2 minutes before asking this question when I noticed it doesn't always work, I thought this was the answer I had been looking for. I didn't want to just un-accept it without a reason or giving a better one. And as fas as "less than a day ago" goes, to my experience, a question on SO is either answered within minutes or never, since there are so many new ones coming in all the time that the old (here: more than an hour) ones get lost in the pile...

Comment: @Markus, any activity on the question will bring it back into the active feed. If you've modified your question to fix typos, or simply commented on it, it will become visible again. Additionally, if you're not getting the traffic you'd like, adding a bounty will help.

Comment: @crowjonah Holy Mother of God!!! JQuery needs close to TWO THOUSAND!!! lines of code (https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/scripts/uncompressed/history.js) to correctly manage all the browser issues associated with this! I can't believe it! So far, this is by far the worst cross-browser-mess I've seen. No wonder I'm having a hard time with this!

Comment: @Markus, it's not written by the jQuery team, it's just an extension to the jQuery library. If that's the worst cross-browser mess you've ever seen, then you obviously haven't looked at jQuery's source code.

Comment: @zzzzBov Correct, I haven't looked at it's source yet. It gets worse? The thing that surprises me about the history management is that this idea of browser history is as old as web-browsers themselves. It's been around for ever. And all it is is a String-list of bookmarks. How can it *possibly* be so complex to make this work right? That's what I meant with worst mess. Clearly, making a canvas work cross browser will be more lines of code, but at least there it makes sense why it's difficult... ;)

Comment: @Markus, the history api is a newer feature to allow rewriting url paths and query strings without needing to reload the page from the server. History.js simplifies most of the common features.

Comment: @MarkusA.It's not hard. Standardizing it was just slow. For now all new browsers support all the history api except two. http://caniuse.com/history I think also that canvas was a priority because it was something that if it didn't exist it would break a website. History hasn't been something that people need to manipulate.